# How to highlight the selected string inside Html tags in Android?

Tags: android, html, css, string, highlight

I have the html tags with strings.I want to search the string using Search button click.I searched the word contains in Html tags.But what i need is,i want to highlight the searched text string.But it's not coming.I used only font color.So the text color only changed.

My code is,

```
text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
      ss="<h1>Soins palliatifs pluridisciplinaires chez un malade en fin de vie." +
            " Accompagnement d'un mourrant et de son entourage</h1><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";

             text.setText(Html.fromHtml(ss));

     et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     search= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

     search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             text.setText(ss);
             String ett =et.getText().toString();
             String tvt =text.getText().toString();

             String  origString = ss.replaceAll(ett,"<font color='yellow'>"+ett+"</font>");
             text.setText(Html.fromHtml(origString));

//             int ofe = tvt.indexOf(ett,0);   
//             SpannableString WordtoSpan = new SpannableString( text.getText() );
//
//     for(int ofs=0;ofs<tvt.length() && ofe!=-1;ofs=ofe+1)
//     {       
//       ofe = tvt.indexOf(ett,ofs);   
//               if(ofe == -1)
//                   break;
//               else
//                   {                       
//
//                   WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), ofe, ofe+ett.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//                  String sss=WordtoSpan.toString();
////                   text.setText(Html.fromHtml(sss), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
//                   text.setText(WordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
//                   
//                   }
//
//        }  


         }
     });

    }
```

Can anyone help me  to highlight the string?

Comment: Highlighting means what exactly you want to do??? Can you show something like exactly how you want.

Comment: I have textView inside Html tags with data's.I have search button.If i search some word using search button,the searched word will highlight in the textview. I couldn't add image.

Comment: Basically you want to set image as background of text. Is this you want?

Comment: No.I dont want to set image.I just to highlight the selected string using html tags.my textview background is white.

Comment: Go to this official page: [http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    String ss="<h1>Soins palliatifs pluridisciplinaires chez un malade en fin de vie." +
            " Accompagnement d'un mourrant et de son entourage</h1><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";

    Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(ss));        
    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 15, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Where 5 is the starting index of text and the 15 is the last Index. Change the color according to your requirement.

Comment: This is for normal string.But i am using Html tags. text.setText(Html.fromHtml(origString));

Comment: It comes.But not exactly.